# How to programmatically determine rather a lazy collection should be loaded?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm not sure how to describe my problem here...

I have a JPA annotated entity which is controlled by hibernate.  I'm using querydsl powered repos to control some of the loading as well.

We have certain fields of our entities which we want to fetch in certain situations, but not in other situations.  Basically the requester of our rest data can use an $expand argument to decide rather to expand the raw data with extra collections.

My problem is that a simple lazy loader does not seem sufficient to prevent loading of these expandable fields of an entity if the user has not requested they be expanded.  Some of our logic automatically runs through all our getter and processes them, and it would therefore always force loading of lazy loaded fields.

I'm wondering if there is a way to programmatically turn 'on' or 'off' fields that I do not want to lazy load from the backend, without detaching the entire entity?

Comment: that's what an EntityGraph is for, tried those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this suggestion does not fit exactly what you expect, but you can set this option (with Hibernate):

**@org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA**

With this option, everything will be set to avoid loading the collection. It provides access to the collection size without loading the items in the collection.